# hunspell accept possessive with word ending with s (trailing apostrophe after s)

Tags: atom-editor, hunspell

How to have hunspell accept possessive (trailing apostrophe) with a plural?
E.g. users'

It took me a long time to figure this out (not an expert in this; just want to have decent spell check when using atom linter-spell for writing latex documents), so I thought it is worthwhile to share it.

Answer (score 2):

I am using dictionaries from https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries

Open en_US.aff with some text editor.

Replace

SFX M Y 1
SFX M   0     's         .

with

SFX M Y 2
SFX M   0     's         .
SFX M   0     s'         .